# Codeigniter advice for creating backend

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

I wold like to make a really small CMS based on codeigniter.

And i would like to get some advice from a more experienced developer.

I was reading through a lot of forums, what would be the best way but i bumped in more like of arguing rather than giving useful info.

So what i would like to do that seems logical to me that have the backend and frontend separated.

Do you think is a good idea?

folder structure

```
[frontend]
  / controllers
  / views
  / models

[backend]
  / config
  / controllers
  / views
  / models
[sysetem]
index.php
```

I was thinking another one, like creating an admin folder in the controllers, models and views but I'm a bit scared of that.

So could someone give me some advice if its possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No You should create admin folder separatly in each controllers, models and views folders. Thats is a good practice. This will make it easier for you to access your controllers, views and models as they will have a centralized single folders.

You should have your directory structure like this:

```
[system]
index.php

[controllers]
   [admin](backend)
   [frontend]

[models]
   [admin](backend)
   [frontend]

[views]
   [admin](backend)
   [frontend]
```

Having directory structure like this is not a good idea and it will make it more complex:

```
[frontend]
  / controllers
  / views
  / models

[backend]
  / config
  / controllers
  / views
  / models
[sysetem]
index.php
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the advice and thank you for the fast reply and spending time on my question